# Magento 2 compile command fail, but no errors

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cli

The compile command suddenly stops, but there is no error.

```
[~/public_html]# php bin/magento setup:di:compile -vvv
Compilation was started.
Repositories code generation... 1/7 [====>-----------------------]  14% 1 sec 198.5 
[~/public_html]#
```

- I set all permissions to 777
- Set mode to "developer"

How can I find the error and fix it?

Comment: Rick, did you find a sollution? I'm facing the same....

Comment: No sorry... still no solution :(

Comment: any one find solution for same

Answer (score 23):

In app/bootstrap.php (line 11).
Enable ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Then run setup:di:compile again, you will see detail error message.
It's already tested.

Comment: display_errors is 1 on mine - no error

Comment: That Worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: Worked like a charm for me. Thanks!

Comment: Worked well for me!!!

Answer (score 2):

Please check log file for the proper error.

We get the same issue at time of code compilation or in production.
We resolved the same issue by removing the unnecessary backup files from the module.

Comment: Thank you so much @prince I have to face the same issue. I have to find the backup file in the config folder. while I have removed backup file in this folder. the compilation is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! I installed al the modules from my life environment into a test and there an error appeared (in development mode). A module was corrupt, so i uninstalled the module and the problem was gone...

Comment: Where did you find the problem? In a file? In your browser?

Comment: In ssh when site is in development mode, it displays the errors then

Comment: Sadly, that's not the case with my Magento 2 installation. I'm in development mode, but no errors :(

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue after extending a class.
The problem was that there was a backslash missing:

**Wrong:**

```
class AbstractProduct extends Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct
```

**Correct:**

```
class AbstractProduct extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct
```